# Python: Converting file to base64 encoding

Tags: python

This is my code:

```
import base64

with open('/Users/Bob/test.txt') as f:
    encoded = base64.b64encode(f.readlines())
    print(encoded)
```

I've based it on the [base64 documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/base64.html). However, when I try running it with Python 2.7.1 and Python 3.2.2 I get the error:

```
    import base64
  File "/Users/Bob/test.txt'", line 4, in <module>
    encoded = base64.b64encode(f.readlines())
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'b64encode'
```

Why can't the `b64encode` attribute be found?

Answer (score 96, accepted):

You have a script named `base64.py` which is shadowing the stdlib module. Rename it.

Comment: Wow, that was super quick! How did you figure out the problem? I did indeed call the file `base64.py`.

Comment: You're not the first to do this.

Comment: by the way, you can simply run this using:

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams and as evidenced by the continued upvotes, not the last one to do this either :)

Comment: I would also like to note that the "f.readlines()" should be "f.read()" as the encoder needs a string. (Tested on mine and had the issue.)

Comment: @Yetti definitely not the last. 7 years later I keep making the same mistakes sometimes