# AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'encode'; base64 encode a pdf file

Tags: python, pdf, post, base64

I am trying to base64 encode a pdf in python. Several SO answers to this worked for other people but not on my end for some reason. My most recent attempt is:

```
# http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12020885/python-converting-file-to-base64-encoding
with open('/home/cchilders/projects/myproject/data/books/software-and-mind.pdf', 'rb') as f:
    encoded = f.read().encode("base64")
    print(encoded)
```

I get

```
AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'encode'
```

How can I base64 this pdf file? Thank you

Comment: `import base64;base64.b64encode(f.read())`

Comment: tried that with readlines. hold on, thank you

Comment: correct, it did not like `readlines` but `read` is fine. if you want to split off I accept

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you should use the base64 module for this

```
import base64
base64.b64encode(f.read())
```