# AttributeError when encoding PNG image into Base64

Tags: python, python-3.x, encoding, base64, attributeerror

I am trying to encode a PNG image into Base64 using this code:

```
for files in os.listdir("."):
if files.endswith(".png"):
    pngFile = open(files, 'rb')
    base64data = pngFile.read().encode('base64').replace('\n','')
    base64String = '<image xlink:href="data:image/png;base64,{0}" width="240" height="240" x="0" y="0" />'.format(base64data)
```

But when I use it it gives an error saying:

```
AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'encode'
```

I have tried lots of solutions like this one:
 [AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'encode'; base64 encode a pdf file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36228117/attributeerror-bytes-object-has-no-attribute-encode-base64-encode-a-pdf-fi) but it just throws another error . BTW I am using python 3

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'encode'; base64 encode a pdf file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36228117/attributeerror-bytes-object-has-no-attribute-encode-base64-encode-a-pdf-fi)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well... I don't know if I should mark this as an answer but I got it working using Python 2.7. Reason unknown.

Answer (score -1):

Try using base64 library

```
import base64

with open(files, "rb") as image_file:
    base64data = base64.b64encode(image_file.read())
    base64String = '<image xlink:href="data:image/png;base64,{0}" width="240" height="240" x="0" y="0" />'.format(base64data)
```

Comment: This did not work it gave me `TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str' ` which means that the solution you have given somehow converts my file into a string but it does not make any sense