# AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'encode' Base64

Tags: python, encoding, crud, bcrypt, fastapi

```sh
File ".\core\users\login.py", line 22, in login_user
    db_user = crud.get_Login(
  File ".\api\crud.py", line 39, in get_Login
    db_user.password.encode('utf-8'))
AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'encode'
```

I got this error to relate to Base64 in Python

This is my `core\users\login.py` :

```py
@router.post("/login")
def login_user(user: schemas.UserLogin, db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    db_user = crud.get_Login(
        db, username=user.username, password=user.password)
    if db_user == False:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=400, detail="Wrong username/password")
    return {"message": "User found"}
```

and `api\crud.py` :

```py
def get_Login(db: Session, username: str, password: str):
    db_user = db.query(models.UserInfo).filter(
        models.UserInfo.username == username).first()
    print(username, password)
    pwd = bcrypt.checkpw(password.encode('utf-8'),
                         db_user.password.encode('utf-8'))
    return pwd
```

I tried this solution and nothing work
[AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'encode'; base64 encode a pdf file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36228117/attributeerror-bytes-object-has-no-attribute-encode-base64-encode-a-pdf-fi)

Comment: I know that I `decode` bytes and `encode` strings, but i tried multiple solutions and nothing work with me

Comment: There is nothing in the code you've shown that has anything to do with Base64, and I don't understand why you would expect it to be relevant here.

Comment: "I know that I `decode` bytes and `encode` strings" Well, what happened when you tried thinking about a) which of those you have in each case; b) which of those you *want* in each case? If you have a `bytes` and want a `bytes`, what should you do to convert it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you encode something you are converting something into bytes, the problem here is that you already have bytes so python is telling that you cant encode that bytes because they are already encoded.

```
my_string          = "Hello World!"
my_encoded_string  = my_string.encode('utf-8')
```

This is ok because im converting str into bytes

```
my_encoded_string  = my_string.encode('utf-8')
foo                = my_encoded_string.encode('utf-8')
```

This will raise an error because my_encoded_string is already encoded

Comment: Thank you Sergio, i got it and its work for me now I understand the converting on this